# Как правильно передать параметры в функцию?

Tags: python, функции, beautiful-soup

Написал парсер в учебных целях, работает. Хотел сделать более оптимизированным. Фрагмент кода который работает исправно

```
try:
    mileage = soup.find('span', class_='label', text='Пробіг') \
        .findNext('span', class_='argument').text
except AttributeError:
    mileage = 'None'
```

Так как в коде присутствует слишком много подобных try/except, решил добавить универсальную функцию которая будет обрабатывать поиск через суп (естественно параметры в первом find и в findNext отличаются для разных случаях). Вот пример того, что хотел сделать (но так не сработало, перепробовал много различных вариантов, это один из наиболее наглядно описывающих проблему).

```
def _try_to_find_info(soup, params_first, params_second):
try:
    return soup.find(params_first).findNext(params_second).text
except AttributeError:
    return 'None'

mileage = _try_to_find_info(soup=soup, params_first=('span', class_='label', text='Пробіг'), params_second=('span', class_='argument'))
```

Пробовал через *args, **kwargs - но видимо уже совсем запутался. Буду очень признателен за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, в моем случае решение такое :

```
def _try_to_find_info_used_auto(soup, params_first, params_second):
try:
    return soup.find(**params_first).findNext(**params_second).text
except AttributeError:
    return 'None'


engine = _try_to_find_info_used_auto(soup=soup, params_first={'name': 'span', 'class_': 'label', 'text': 'Двигун'}, params_second={'name': 'span', 'class_': 'argument'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда Вы в исходном варианте пишете

```
soup.find('span', class_='label', text='Пробіг')
```

то Вы передаёте в метод *find()* **три** параметра.

А когда в модифицированном варианте пишете

```
soup.find(params_first)
```

то передаёте **один** параметр. А то, чтот параметр - список из
трёх элементов, ничего не меняет. Это всё равно - один параметр.

Comment: Да, это я понимаю. Такой пример более всего наглядно описывает идею того, как я хочу сделать. А вот как их правильно передать - пока не придумал. Ладно если бы это было ещё в одном месте (было бы проще), но надо сделать в двух. Плюс ко всему ещё для find и findNext передаю параметры такие как «class_=‘value’”, естественно функция читает их как именованные параметры, что прибавляет сложности

Comment: @VladyslavVovchuk -"как их правильно передать"
- В программирование самое правильное решение - самое простое.Если Вам нужно передать в функцию пять параметров, ну так и передавайте - **пять** параметров! Ну а если очень хочется передать одним параметром - списком, то в функции надо эти 5 значений присвоить пяти локальным переменным, а потом подставить эти локальные переменные в вызов *soup.find()*